# How to automatically update after checking the app version in Ionic App

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, capacitor, auto-update

I'm making a hybrid app using Ionic/capacitor.

After distributing the app to the Play Store/App Store, proceed with the update.

When a user accesses the app, they want to show a message telling them to use the app after the update and let them use the app after the update.

How should I implement that function?

Should I use AppUpdate to check the version?

Comment: use this plugin: https://github.com/robingenz/capacitor-app-update